# Profile/Edit/Change Picture has the least obvious user path I have ever seen

Tags: feature-request, support

When I click the Change Picture link, I am simply taken to the front page of the Gravatar site, with absolutely no explanation of what I should be doing there.

Clicking the Change Picture link should take you to an intermediate page that at least explains what Stackoverflow wants you to accomplish there, and how to close the "Change Picture" loop.

I've now followed the link several times.  I created a Gravatar account, waited for confirmation mail, uploaded a picture, etc.  Yet, when I am at Stackoverflow and go back to Profile/Edit/Change Picture, I am still simply taken to the front page of Gravatar.

Is there a reason Stackoverflow has to be this obtuse about Change Picture?  If not, please fix.

Comment: Perhaps renaming that link to "Change your Gravatar" would already lead to less confusion about the redirection? Then something named "Gravatar" showing up would not be a complete surprise.

Comment: I would still explain to the user that what they want to do at Gravatar (after they have created a membership, etc) is to 1. add the email address you gave to stackoverflow and 2. associate a picture with that email address.

Comment: I would also explain that the given Gravatar will also be associated with any accounts you have anywhere else on the internet where you have used that email and the site uses Gravatar...